# How to prevent Ember.js 1.0.0 from removing URL parameters?

Tags: ember.js

I use Ember 1.0.0 and i can not update to new versions now. I need a solution for Ember 1.0.0.

For example Google Adwords needs to pass custom parameters to visited website so Analytics can measure the traffic. I need to have it.

So for example URL is: mywebsite.com/someemberpage/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_term=test&utm_content=test&utm_campaign=test

But after website loads Ember strips custom parameter. How to prevent it without updating Ember.js?

( In case Ember does not strip custom parameters please write, because if so, some JS code on my website does this. Thanks! )

Comment: What do you mean by "without updating Ember.js"? I think if you specify the queryparams in your controller, the queryparams won't be stripped (https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/query-params/#toc_specifying-query-parameters).

Comment: @Sandro Munda I don't think queryparameters method is available in Ember.js 1.0.0. The docs you sent are for v.2.6.0. I can not update to this version now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecated but these might be what your looking for...

- https://github.com/knownasilya/ember-query-params
- https://github.com/alexspeller/ember-query

In the past we used ember-query-params.  It did the job just fine.

Hope this helps,

Jeff